# can I use .h5 file in Django project?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, web, artificial-intelligence

I'm making AI web page using Django and tensor flow. and I wonder how I add .h5 file in Django project.

writing whole code in views.py file
but I want to use pre-trained model
not online learning in webpage.

Comment: I think you mean how to load a .h5 model into django? Because the answer below is about opening a h5 file with h5py, which is not the same as using load_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah u can use `.h5` file in django. You can use [h5py](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/) for operations on `.h5` files. Exapmle -

```py
import h5py

filename = "filename.h5"

h5 = h5py.File(filename,'r')

# logic
...

h5.close()
```